# Average speed of molecular effusion

Tags: particle-physics, statistical-mechanics

I need know what is the average speed of molecular effusion I mean the speed of a particle that scape from a container. NOT the rate of molecular effusion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effusion

Comment: The average (RMS) speed of molecules which escape will be the same as the average speed of molecules in the container, which depends on the temperature : $v=\sqrt{3kT/m}$.

Comment: But the speed that you show me is the most probable speed it isn't the average speed. Or well, how you obtain that expression ?